Minimum amount order different per country and fee to certain country
I have tried some hooks for WooCommerce but not managed to get it to work so I wonder if someone could help. Using elementor if that makes any difference.
I added a plugin and that works ok for Sweden minimum order 300 but not getting it to work to get a minimum order for DK, NO and FI for 1000. I also like to add an extra fee of 100 for orders to DK, FI and NO.
So this is what I need.

Minimum order amount of 300 for SE
Minimum order amount of 1000 for NO, DK and FI
Extra fee added to all orders to NO, DK and FI of 100

Tried this code for fee in php file but did not work:
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', function() {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return;
    }
    
    $shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
    if ($shipping_country == 'NO, DK, FI') {
        WC()->cart->add_fee(__('Administrativ kostnad export', 'txtdomain'), 100);
    }
});

Tried this code for fee in php file but did not work:
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', function() {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return;
    }
    
    $shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
    if ($shipping_country == 'NO, DK, FI') {
        WC()->cart->add_fee(__('Administrativ kostnad export', 'txtdomain'), 100);
    }
});

Also tried a plug in (WPFactory - order minimum/maximum amount for woocommerce) that works for SE but not for the other countries. Might work with the pro version but not sure and dont want to pay for something that might not work. This plug-in also have a section called fee but cannot find information on how that would look or if I can set it to certain countries.
And lastly tried this php code in WPcode but it says it is wrong and not working:
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'reguired_min_cart_subtotal_amount' );
function required_min_cart_subtotal_amount() {
    
    //HERE Set minimum cart total amount
    $minimum_amount = 300;
    
    //Total (before taxes and shipping charges)
    $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    
    //Add an error notice is cart total is less than the minimum required
        if( $cart_subtotal < $minimum_amount  )  {
        // Display an error message
        wc_add_notice( '<strong>'. sprintf( _(“Ett lägsta värde om 300 kr krävs för beställning.”), wc_price($minimum_amount)  ) .  '</strong>', 'error' );
    }
}

